# Video Compression using Telegram's Code Android - Output surface wait timed out | MediaCodec

Tags: java, android, android-mediacodec

The code I'm using is from this repo : https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/

In the ~/src/main/java/org/telegram/android/video/MediaController class where the encoder and decoder are instantiated, I'm getting "Sufrace wait timed out exception" in the OutputSurface class no matter what video I'm choosing.

Tried on devices : Nexus 4 (Lollipop), Asus Zenfone 5 (Kitkat), Moto G (Kitkat).

Is there anything that I'm missing? I have not changed the code at all.

-- code snippet from MediaController.java --

```
if (!decoderDone) {
                                        int decoderStatus = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, TIMEOUT_USEC);
                                        if (decoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                                            decoderOutputAvailable = false;
                                        } else if (decoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
                                    } else if (decoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                                        MediaFormat newFormat = decoder.getOutputFormat();
                                        Log.e("tmessages", "newFormat = " + newFormat);
                                    } else if (decoderStatus < 0) {
                                        throw new RuntimeException("unexpected result from decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " + decoderStatus);
                                    } else {
                                        boolean doRender = false;
                                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
                                            doRender = info.size != 0;
                                        } else {
                                            doRender = info.size != 0 || info.presentationTimeUs != 0;
                                        }
                                        if (endTime > 0 && info.presentationTimeUs >= endTime) {
                                            inputDone = true;
                                            decoderDone = true;
                                            doRender = false;
                                            info.flags |= MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM;
                                        }
                                        if (startTime > 0 && videoTime == -1) {
                                            if (info.presentationTimeUs < startTime) {
                                                doRender = false;
                                                Log.e("tmessages", "drop frame startTime = " + startTime + " present time = " + info.presentationTimeUs);
                                            } else {
                                                videoTime = info.presentationTimeUs;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(decoderStatus, doRender);
                                        if (doRender) {
                                            boolean errorWait = false;
                                            try {
                                                outputSurface.awaitNewImage();
                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                Log.e("wait",""+true);
                                                errorWait = true;
                                                Log.e("tmessages", e.getMessage());
                                            }
                                            if (!errorWait) {
                                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
                                                    outputSurface.drawImage(false);
                                                    inputSurface.setPresentationTime(info.presentationTimeUs * 1000);
                                                    inputSurface.swapBuffers();
                                                } else {
                                                    int inputBufIndex = encoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
                                                    if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                                                        outputSurface.drawImage(true);
                                                        ByteBuffer rgbBuf = outputSurface.getFrame();
                                                        ByteBuffer yuvBuf = encoderInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];
                                                        yuvBuf.clear();
                                                        convertVideoFrame(rgbBuf, yuvBuf, colorFormat, resultWidth, resultHeight, padding, swapUV);
                                                        encoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, bufferSize, info.presentationTimeUs, 0);
                                                    } else {
                                                        Log.e("tmessages", "input buffer not available");
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                                            decoderOutputAvailable = false;
                                            Log.e("tmessages", "decoder stream end");
                                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
                                                encoder.signalEndOfInputStream();
                                            } else {
                                                int inputBufIndex = encoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
                                                if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                                                    encoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, 1, info.presentationTimeUs, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
```

-- code snippet from OutputSurface.java --

```
public void awaitNewImage() {
        final int TIMEOUT_MS = 2500;
        synchronized (mFrameSyncObject) {
            while (!mFrameAvailable) {
                try {
                    mFrameSyncObject.wait(TIMEOUT_MS);
                    if (!mFrameAvailable) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Surface frame wait timed out");
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ie);
                }
            }
            mFrameAvailable = false;
        }
        mTextureRender.checkGlError("before updateTexImage");
        mSurfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
    }

public void drawImage(boolean invert) {
    mTextureRender.drawFrame(mSurfaceTexture, invert);
}

@Override
public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture st) {
    Log.d("frame ","new frame");
    synchronized (mFrameSyncObject) {
        if (mFrameAvailable) {
            throw new RuntimeException("mFrameAvailable already set, frame could be dropped");
        }
        mFrameAvailable = true;
        mFrameSyncObject.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

These code snippets might not make a lot of sense and can't post the complete code here because its huge. You can find the complete code here : https://github.com/316karan/mediacodec-tele

The problem is I never receive any frame on the OutputSurface and it goes in a an infinite loop with timeouts.

Comment: please be more specific about the problem. also share the code you are using to help solve your problem.

Comment: @Blip. Thanks for the reply. Added code snippets and pushed the complete code on git. https://github.com/316karan/mediacodec-tele

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457623/surfacetextures-onframeavailable-method-always-called-too-late please look here, morelikely you have to put your stuff to the right thread

Comment: I have shared how I was able to resolve the issue here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55968224/2326325

Answer (score 0):

do not block the main thread. run that method in another thread